# Attach debug to process Unity doesn't work

Tags: unity-game-engine

I created new 3d unity project, then in asserts I created c# script if I click on it twice Visual Studio 2017 is opened. Then I would like to make a debug, so I set debug point and click in Unity on play button and nothing happes.

[image]

There is no attach button or something like this.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess you are might not attaching your Visual Studio with the Unity. There is a button (Run or Play) Button. in your case, this is the Start Button, and in my Visual studio it is called (Attach to Unity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens randomly to me as well. The way I fix it it to go **Unity->Edit Menu->Preferences->External Tools**, and set the External Script Editor to something else, and then revert it back to Visual Studio.

If that fails, just underneath that dropdown there is a button **Regenerate Project Files**, which helps when your VS project files get messed up.

Also, upgrading to the latest version of Visual Studio and Unity Tools for VS could help.

Answer (score 0):

My bad if I misunderstood this question, but all you have to do for unity to update your scripts for your game is ctrl + s, this will let unity know you made changes to the script and it will apply those changes.